# How I can decode codes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, decode, decoder

I trying to decode like this code.
I tried a lot of sites but none of them work.

```js
var _0x2b10=['Hello\x20tito!'];(function(_0x3f112f,_0x2b10bf){var _0x5a86d2=function(_0x5e1f9d){while(--_0x5e1f9d){_0x3f112f['push'](_0x3f112f['shift']());}};_0x5a86d2(++_0x2b10bf);}(_0x2b10,0x16d));var _0x5a86=function(_0x3f112f,_0x2b10bf){_0x3f112f=_0x3f112f-0x0;var _0x5a86d2=_0x2b10[_0x3f112f];return _0x5a86d2;};function tito(){console['log'](_0x5a86('0x0'));}tito();
```

Can you give me a site that can decode this kind of code?

Comment: Please ask only the programming related questions.

Answer (score 1):

The code is already ''decoded'', you can run it just fine, it's just been made to be deliberately confusing.

Although, you can make it more understandable by renaming the variables to something more readable like var1 instead of _0x2b10 and by properly indenting the code.

```js
var var1=['Hello\x20tito!'];
(function(var2, var3){
    var var5=function(var6){
        while(--var6){
            var2['push'](var2['shift']());
        }
    };
    var5(++var3);
}(var1,0x16d));
var var4=function(var2,var3){
    var2 = var2 - 0x0;
    var var5=var1[var2];
    return var5;
};
function tito(){
    console.log(var4('0x0'));
}
tito();
```